# Relationship Between Students, Parents and Guardians

Tags: mysql, database-design

Assume I use MySQL, and there are two tables, `students` and `parents_guardians` table. Table `students` is used to store students' data. The `parents_guardians` table is used to store students' parents and  students' guardians.

So either a student can have a father and a mother as his parents, or a student can have an uncle and an aunt as his guardians. To do that, I add one more table as pivot table, which is `students_parents_guardians` table.

This pivot table contains 3 columns:

1. `students_id`
2. `parents_id`
3. `guardians_id`

The question is:
Is this good design? And how can I do that in Laravel?

So far, I'm unable to do that. What I can do is create 5 table:

1. `students` table to store student's data
2. `parents` table to store parents' data
3. `students_parents` as pivot table to perform relationship between students
   and parents.
4. `guardians` table to store guardian's data
5. `students_guardians` as pivot table to perform relationship bwtween students
   and guardians.

I believe this is a bad idea, and I should normalize all of it.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to  the forum! A [linking table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity#:~:text=An%20associative%20entity%20is%20a,%2C%20informally%2C%20an%20associative%20table.) is what you are looking for! But why have separate `parent` and `guardian` tables? A parent is automatically a guardian. Have a `guardian` table with an `is_parent` Boolean field! 5 tables -> 3!

Comment: Both guardians and parents I think it should be on the same table. But in this case I should separate it in different tables because I got some difficult in perform a relationship if we put them in the same table. Do you have a solution to do this?

Comment: Not much more complexity (`WHERE is_parent = [TRUE | FALSE]`)! **Plus**, it will greatly simplify queries for both, **and**, as has been pointed out, the distinction  between parent and guardian for a school is probably minimal!

Comment: I am using Laravel to implement it, it's such a bit difiicult to explain here, because it will take many lines of code. Could you show me the more detail clue and tutorial?

Comment: I've never used Laravel (or PHP for that matter) so I can't help out with any tutorials - you'd be better placed to know a decent one than I would! AFAICS, it's pretty straightforward - just create a `guardian` table with an `is_parent` BOOLEAN field  **Very important** - what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Vérace:  I don't understand completely especially when I do relationship between them. If this is the solution, then I should create 2 pivot table. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am **suggesting** that you have a tables called `student` & `guardian` and an [`associative entity`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) called `g_s` with an `is_parent` field (as per the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b951b1408ceb328d5a95e2bb8581b00c)). Now, short of me writing your Laravel/PHP (know **nothing** about either) code for you, I don't see how I can contribute further! This is simpler than your original schema - a parent **may** or **may** not be a guardian of their own or other children-this schema (AFAICS) encapsulates all possibilites!

Comment: @Vérace: I always refer to this site https://medium.com/hackernoon/eloquent-relationships-cheat-sheet-5155498c209 to do most relationship cases. But in this case I've found some of diffcult to implement it... Need more clue and more explanation.

Comment: This is the last time I reply - your problem is **now** a Laravel/PHP/programming one. You should go to StackOverflow.com and ask there! You have a recommended many-to-many table structure - how you implement this is PHP/Laravel is completely out of scope for this forum (and for me - not knowing anything about either) and is off-topic! If you have further **database** problems - ask here - this is where they belong. Programming questions (other than SQL) belong on StackOverflow! You've already used that site, so please post to the appropriate site! Best of luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

Your design with 5 tables is more [normalized](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) than your initial design, and makes more sense.

When you say "pivot table" it sounds like you mean a linking table. Since the relationship between `students` and `parents` (and also between `students` and `guardians`) is a **many-to-many** relationship being that a student can have up to two parents, and a parent can have multiple children (students) then this is the proper way to relate the two tables in a normalized form, and good design.

The only thing I think you could do is consolidate the `parents` and `guardians` into one Table (assuming they have basically the same attributes) and have a `type` field to determine if it's a parent or guardian. If there's only two types, you can use a boolean datatype field called `IsParent`, or with more types you can create an enum table called `RelationshipTypes` (or something similar) and store the ID in your consolidated Table, for normalization.

The `IsParent` field would be best to put on the linking table, that way a `Guardian` can be a parent to one `Student` but only a `Guardian` to another `Student` (who isn't related by blood) in cases of like adoption, etc.

Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04f18fa/1/0) to illustrate the above, with some tweaks.

Comment: I would [avoid](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-my) the ENUM type if possible!

Comment: @Vérace Sorry I wasn't implying the ENUM datatype (I thought that was explicit enough by saying the `ID` would be stored in the Parent/Guardian table, and the value in another table). Rather I meant a table with a fixed number of rows to represent an "enum". Just updated my answer to clarify that, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Definitely this.  And absolutely consolidate the parent and guardian table.  In a system you track the data that you care about.  The biological distinction between a parent and a guardian might be of interest in some systems, but in a school system there is absolutely nothing important about the distinction between a parent and a guardian. They are legally the same as far as the school is concerned and will have all of the same attributes and relationships, so there's no good reason at all for keeping these two types of data in different tables.

Comment: Reorganizing tables for subtyping is not normalization.

Comment: @Philipxy That's potentially debatable, but the part that my answer states is normalization is using a `RelationshipTypes` table to refactor out the value and only reference the type by `ID`

Comment: Assume, there is person A, and this person can be parent and guardian in the same time. If we separate a parents and guardian in different table, let's say, person A with ID 4312 is exist in parents table, and in the same time, this person ( person A with ID 4312) is exist in guardian table as well. With this way, we will get the duplicate data, which is not good, right? Because it will lead to another problems. So, the question is: How can I avoid this duplicate data?

Comment: Both guardians and parents I think it should be on the same table. But in this case I should separate it in different tables because I got some difficult in perform a relationship if we put them in the same table. Do you have a solution to do this?

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq Yes so that's the point of my last paragraph is have one `Table` for `Parents` and `Guardians`, and have a field called `IsParent` to determine which one it is. If this doesn't solve your problem, please explain further what is the "difficult relationship" issue.

Comment: @J.D.: I am using Laravel to implement it, it's such a bit difiicult to explain here, because it will take many lines of code. Could you show me the more detail clue and tutorial?

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq Laravel is a PHP framework and not related to your question on Table schema design. All I'm saying is you don't need 2 tables for `Parents` and `Guardians`, just 1 table `ParentsOrGuardians` (I'd actually shorten the name to just `Guardians` for better naming convention, since "Parents" are technically "Guardians") with an ID PK field `ParentOrGuardianId`. Then your linking table `Students_ParentsOrGuardians` would contain the `StudentId` and the `ParentOrGuardianId`. The `ParentsOrGuardians` table would have a field `IsParent` to determine if it is a "Parent" or "Guardian".

Comment: @J.D.: I don't understand completely especially when I do relationship between them. If this is the solution, then I should create 2 pivot table. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq A picture's worth 1,000 words, please see this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04f18fa/1/0) of the schema I'm describing (with some tweaks). You only need one linking table to accomplish this (3 tables total: `Students`, `Guardians`, and the linking table between them `StudentsGuardians`).